# function invocation pattern scoping rules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is a working example from "Javascript - The Good Parts".

```
function add(x, y){ return x + y};

var myObject = {
    value: 0,
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value); 

myObject.double = function (  ) {
    var that = this;    // Workaround.

    var helper = function (  ) {
        that.value = add(that.value, that.value)
    };

    helper(  );    // Invoke helper as a function.
};

myObject.double(  );
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 4
```

For function invocation pattern, 'this' object will have global reference. But I cannot fully understand under-the-hood of mentioned workaround:-

```
var that = this;    // Workaround.
```

if we do this, aren't we just copying the reference to 'this' to 'that' ? i.e 'that' will hold to global scope same as 'this' ? how does this work internally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two functions being involved here: one is `myObject.double` and the other is `helper`. When you call `myObject.double()` this refers to `myObject`. So `that === myObject`. Later, inside that function, you also call `helper()`, and inside that scope you have `this === the global object`.

Answer (score 10):

It's not the same here, `this` refers to `myObject` so you're getting the right `value` property it has, `this` would refer to `window`...which is why you want to keep the reference like it's doing.

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KSty9/1/), a few alerts inside the `helper` function show what's happening pretty well.

An alternative would be to [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the function with the right context, so `this` continues to refer to the `myObject` instance you want...like this:

```
myObject.double = function () {
    var helper = function () {
        this.value = add(this.value, this.value)
    };
    helper.call(this);    // Invoke helper as a function.
};
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KSty9/2/).

Comment: Also, in the book mentioned (Javascript The Good Parts), the previous paragraph explains clearly about `The Method Invocation Pattern`: `When a function is stored as a property of an object, we call it a method. When a method is invoked, this is bound to that object.` , in your case `myObject.double = function (  ) {... };` is your Method Invocation Pattern, hence when within it, `this` refers to `myObject`

Comment: Another thing to note: the example provided uses `inner function` for the `Function Invocation Pattern`. I created a much simpler example to illustrate the logic, see http://jsbin.com/ciriwabeliwi/1/edit?js,console . Finally, the example provided by the book is equivalent to http://jsbin.com/roheyekonabe/1/edit?js,console